# Holomorphic function in some open set

Tags: complex-analysis

$f:\mathbb{C^{*}} \to \mathbb{C} \\ \quad \; z \to \frac{1}{z^2} + |z|^2 $

Exploring the possibility of the existence of a non-empty open set $U$ of $\mathbb{C^*}$ such that $f|_{U}$ is holomorphic; I did the following:

Let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C^*}$; $\mathit{C} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z|=|z_0| \}$, then:

$$lim_{z \to z_0;z \in \mathit{C}} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = lim_{z \to z_0;z \in \mathit{C}} \frac{\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z_0^2}}{z-z_0} + \frac{|z|^2-|z_0|^2}{z-z_0}=lim_{z \to z_0;z \in \mathit{C}} \frac{\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{z_0^2}}{z-z_0}=-\frac{2}{{z_0}^3}$$

For $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z=\lambda z_0; \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}:
lim_{z \to z_0;z \in D} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=lim_{\lambda \to 1} \frac{\frac{1}{\lambda^2 z_{0}^2}-\frac{1}{z_0^2}}{\lambda z_0-z_0} + \frac{|\lambda z_0|^2-|z_0|^2}{\lambda z_0-z_0}=lim_{\lambda \to 1} -\frac{(1+ \lambda)}{z_0^3}+ (\lambda+1) \frac{|z_0|}{z_0}= -\frac{2}{z_0^3}+ 2\frac{|z_0|}{z_0} \neq -\frac{2}{z_0^3}; (z_0 \in \mathbb{C^{*}}) $

And from here, I concluded that f cannot be holomorphic in any non-empty (open) set of the domain. Is this approach correct? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ was holomorphic in some open subset, then $g(z)=f(z)-\dfrac{1}{z^2}=|z|^2$ would be holomorphic in that subset too.

But the only real holomorphic functions are constant and $g$ isn't on any open subset, so we reach a contradiction.